# Generate auto increment sequence in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am pushing logs to Elastic Search from Logstash and then i need to get back the logs in the order they were written. Sorting by time stamp does not help because there could me multiple log statements in the same time. I followed the solution in [Include monotonically increasing value in logstash field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920655/include-monotonically-increasing-value-in-logstash-field/39265235) and it worked perfectly in my windows system.

But when the code was moved to the linux production environment, logstash is not starting up. Failing with the below error

> reason=>"Couldn't find any filter plugin named 'seq'. Are you sure
>   this is correct? Trying to load the seq filter plugin resulted in this
>   error: no such file to load -- logstash/filters/seq", :level=>:error}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the seq.rb file is in the filter folder.
Also check if the line ending of your seq.rb are linux. If you transferred the file from a windows machine to a linux, the problem might come from here.

Comment: Thanks.. I corrected the line endings and also moved the logstash folder(which was previously inside lib) to a customFilters folder and started logstash with this --> bin/logstash --pluginpath customFilters -f logstash-local.conf. It is now working fine.